# execl parameters confusion

Tags: c, system, execl

Why does the command
`execl("/bin/ls", NULL);`
return a usage error, whereas the command
`execl("/bin/ls", "badfsafds", NULL);`
return a list of files in the directory in a simple C program?

I know that the first parameter of execl is path specification, but I thought it was only for path specification, not command execution. Thank you.

Comment: Q: Is your question resolved?  The basic problem (per the example in my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66393258/3135317) below) was your assumption that the 1st "arg" parameter in [execl()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) was the 1st argument passed to "/bin/ls".  It isn't.  By convention, the 1st argument ("argv[0]") is actually the name/filepath of the program being executed. 'Hope that clarifies things... at least a bit...

Comment: It is resolved! The solutions below are very helpful.

Comment: "The solutions below are very helpful"  Then please be sure to "upvote" and/or "accept" the responses you found helpful ;)

Comment: I will be sure to do this once I have more than 15 reputation!

Comment: well here's a +1 ;)

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter specifies the path, yes.

The second and subsequent parameters give the arguments which are passed to the program, e.g. as its `argv` argument to `main()`, starting with `argv[0]`.

So your first example causes `ls` to run with an empty `argv` vector, in which `argv[0]` is NULL.  Most programs assume that `argv[0]` will be a valid string which specifies the name of the program in some form or other, and they will crash or otherwise not work if it is NULL.  Thus you should not do this.

Your second example causes `ls` to run with `argv[0]` set to `"badfsafds"` and no other arguments.  The unusual value for `argv[0]` probably won't affect its behavior for the most part.  But for instance if it gives an error message, say if you run it in a directory for which you don't have read permissions, it will include the given `argv[0]` and report something like `badfsafds: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`.  Other than that, it works just like any other time you run `ls` from your shell with no arguments, and lists the current directory.

(Some programs do change their behavior depending on the value of `argv[0]`.  For instance, on my system `cal` and `ncal` are symlinks to the same executable.  This executable looks at its `argv[0]` to determine how it was run, and depending whether it sees `cal` or `ncal` it will adjust its output format accordingly.  But I don't think `ls` has any such behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example of correct usage:

> https://linuxhint.com/exec_linux_system_call_c/
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> int main(void) {
>   char *binaryPath = "/bin/ls";
>   char *arg1 = "-lh";
>   char *arg2 = "/home";
>  
>   execl(binaryPath, binaryPath, arg1, arg2, NULL);
>  
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

You'll notice that if you print `argv[0]` of any standard C program, it will show you the command that's being executed.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: in all explanation below, it is assumed that you use the convention of calling `argc` and `argv` to the parameters of `main()` routine, if you don't call them like here, then you'll need to change the names where they appear below.)

The parameters to `execl()` are, in order:

- the first is the file name to be loaded for execution.  This is used by the kernel to get the program loaded on memory.  This string is used only by the kernel and the executed program doesn't have access to it.
- the second is `argv[0]`, this is, the program name (again).  You can put any other string that will be seen from the inside of the new program as `argv[0]`.  (see below for a funny effect of this)
- the third, etc. are the command line arguments, and will appear as `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc. upto a final `NULL` value that indicates to `execl` the end of the list of arguments.  This is also seen in the program as `argv[argc]`, and is also equal to `NULL`.

so, to call `ls`, you need to use:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
```

or, if you want to pass it arguments:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "/etc/passwd", NULL);
```

the first call you used gives you an error because you pass `NULL` as the program name (`argv[0]`), the second is accepted but as a call to ls with a wrong name (which `ls` internally doesn't mind if you change it) and no command line parameters, so it lists the directory `"."`.

To be valid you could call `execl` as:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "What the hell?", "badfsafds", NULL);
```

and you should get:

```
What the hell?: badfsafds: No such file or directory
```

and you'll see that, despite of not checking that it has been called with a different name than the file that was loaded, it uses it to announce itself in the error message.

Comment: Very good example illustrating "argv[0]" usage. Thank you for sharing :)